# SNMP table with V3 pysnmp - reg

Tags: python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

I am trying to create the SNMP table with SNMP v3. I followed this documentation and was able to create SNMP table using v2c and get response. When I tried modifying the user registration part to support V3 there was no response to the manager.

Link followed: https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html

Topic:
Implementing conceptual table

I modified this part

[image]

to

[image]

But the code worked in v2c and not in V3

Comment: Version 3 communication can fail on a few cases, and wrong user configuration is just one of them. So you still need to debug further into the agent source code and see what else you missed.

Comment: I have checked the authentication part it works when I send data normally but the data is not getting passed when I try to implement SNMP tables. 
I dont know how to do context name registration for the SNMP tables.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in `addVacmUser` where you should use `authPriv`, not `authNoPriv`. So, this is just a "typo" level issue, and nothing is wrong with PySNMP.

Your manager side code got nothing back, and that was actually caused by a bug in PySNMP RFC3414 support, which was recently resolved in `pysnmp-lextudio`.